# What is this grass that is growing in my desert yard?

Tags: grass, desert

I live in New Mexico (zone 7a) and my yard is basically a desert. However, I was surprised to discover some grass growing near the edge of my patio slab today. I didn't plant it and I certainly haven't watered it, so I was surprised to see it!

I'm hoping someone can identify what this stuff is so maybe I can plant it elsewhere since it seems to like growing here!

Bigger versions here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhLg1.jpg

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm starting to worry that they're sticker burrs. :(

Comment: I don't know what the grass is, but the reason its growing where it is is because its near a paving slab - the soil beneath stone will be damper than exposed ground, so there's no guarantee that whatever it is will grow well in the rest of your plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It grew up to be a kind of Foxtail. This stuff grows really well and produces a nice green grass--but eventually becomes an annoying Foxtail, spreads its seeds, and then immediately dies.